# Generating arrays from command response with Bash

Tags: bash, shell, terminal

In my shell, I am running the following command:

```
RESPONSE=($(chrome-cli list windows))
```

My response from this looks like this:

```
[32] Reading output of a command into an array in Bash - Stack Overflow
[52] Apple
```

What I am trying to do is create an array from the response like so: [32, 52] so I can iterate over them to run more commands.

I have tried a good few things but I am getting nowhere.

Comment: Do you mean you want an array consisting of the two elements `32` and `52`?

Comment: Process out the additional information so that your response is `32 52` (with optional linefeed in between if you prefer). You can then access e.g. `${RESPONSE[0]}` or loop over the values

Comment: I did try that but i ended up with a string with huge spaces and when i put it into an array it was all messed up

Comment: I still don't understand what your array should look like. The current answer assumes you want the number in brackets to be the index and the rest of the line the values. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand you want an array that contains windows' IDs.

```
ar=($(chrome-cli list windows | cut -d " " -f 1 | sed 's/.$//; s/^.//'))
echo ${ar[@]}
```

In your example output will be `32 52`

Comment: I have not tried this yet as i am away for the night but you are right i am truing to get the windows ids out in an array to loop over

Comment: Tried it just now and it works exactly how i wanted thank you

Answer (score 1):

That could be a somehow ugly solution:

```
echo "$a"   #no chrome-cli in my system
[32] Reading output of a command into an array in Bash - Stack Overflow
[52] Apple

declare -a printf "arr=($(sed 's/] /]=\"/g; s/$/\"/g; s/$\n//g' <<<"$a"))"
echo "${arr[32]}"
Reading output of a command into an array in Bash - Stack Overflow
echo "${arr[52]}"
Apple
declare -p arr
#Result: declare -a arr=([32]="Reading output of a command into an array in Bash - Stack Overflow" [52]="Apple")
```